# How to provide different error messages for min, max in isLength type validation under checkSchema of express-validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am looking for a solution to provide different error messages in express-validator where the options can contain more than one value like **isLength** which can take min and max value.

```
var validation_rules = checkSchema({
    first_name: {
        notEmpty: {
            errorMessage: 'The First Name field is required'
        },
        isString: {
            errorMessage: 'The First Name must be a string.'
        },
        isLength: {
            options: { min: 3, max: 4 }
        }
    }
});
```

As my example, I want to provide different error messages for min and max validation.

> for min - The First Name must be at least 3 characters.
>
> for max - The First Name may not be greater than 50 characters.

But I can only provide a single errorMessage here which is commonly used for both types of validation.

Can someone tell me how this can possible in express-validator checkSchema validation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating a custom validator. In this custom validator check the length of your First-name with different conditions and for each invalid conditions reject with a promise your error message.

```
var validation_rules = checkSchema({
    first_name: {
        notEmpty: {
            errorMessage: 'The First Name field is required'
        },
        isString: {
            errorMessage: 'The First Name must be a string.'
        },
        custom: value => {
            if (value.length < 3) {
             return Promise.reject("The First Name is too short")
            } else if (value.length > 4) {
             return Promise.reject("The First Name is too long")
            }
            return Promise.resolve()
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do I need to create a custom validator if the package(express-validator) already provide us?

Comment: The package express-validator doesn't provide a way to set different error messages for one validator with different options (like the isLength min-max). So if you want to have different error messages (one for Min & one for Max) , the only way is to create a custom validator.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Lasmala's answer did not work for me. The following worked in express-validator version 6.10.1:

```
exports.addUser = [
    checkSchema({
        first_name: {
            isLength: {
                errorMessage: "first_name has invalid length. Send between 1 and 100 characters",
                options: { min: 1, max: 100},
            },
            isString: {
                errorMessage: 'first_name must be a string'
            },
        },
    }),
]
```

With the length validation, you cover the notEmpty validator. After that, you import the function and add it to a router like so:

```
Router.post('/user', Validator.addUser, validate, Controller.addUser);
```

Validate is a simple function that does this (so you do not have to do it in the controller):

```
exports.validate = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
      return next();
    }
    return res.status(422).send(errors.array());
}
```

Got some of that code from the [official documentation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/schema-validation.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can split built in `isLength` `min` and `max` validator and use custom message for each like this:

```
body('password')
  .isLength({ min: 8 })
  .withMessage('Password must be at least 8 characters')
  .isLength({ max: 128 })
  .withMessage('Password cannot exceed 128 characters'),
```

Working for me in "express-validator": 7.0.1

Comment: I asked this question 4 years ago and at that time such methods were not available. Appreciate your answer [based on the latest version].